# Is there any way to identify tab view in an android app?

Tags: android

Now I want to identify tab views in an android app, I try to use adb shell dumpsys to dump activity infos for seeking some common characteristics in tab views. However, the results differ in different apps. For example, I use `adb shell dumpsys activity package.name`, and I get this info from its results:

```
android.widget.TabWidget{3630102 V.E...... ........ 0,2188-1600,2380 #1020013 android:id/tabs}
                    android.widget.FrameLayout{5023a13 VF....... ........ 0,0-320,192}
                      android.widget.RelativeLayout{d56b450 V.E...C.. ........ 0,0-320,192 #7f09055a app:id/vgTab}
                        android.widget.RelativeLayout{ebb5649 V.E...... ........ 100,0-220,192 #7f090518 app:id/vgItem}
                          android.widget.ImageView{f842b4e V.ED..... ........ 0,32-120,110 #7f090201 app:id/ivTabItem}
                          android.widget.ImageView{ccc646f G.ED..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0904da app:id/vCrumb}
                          android.widget.TextView{67ac57c V.ED..... ........ 24,116-96,165 #7f09042f app:id/tvName}
                      android.widget.ImageView{45a0e05 G.ED..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0901c4 app:id/imvVip}
                    android.widget.FrameLayout{77bae5a VF....... ..S..... 320,0-640,192}
                      android.widget.RelativeLayout{264d88b V.E...C.. ..S..... 0,0-320,192 #7f09055a app:id/vgTab}
                        android.widget.RelativeLayout{56cbd68 V.E...... ..S..... 100,0-220,192 #7f090518 app:id/vgItem}
                          android.widget.ImageView{7728581 V.ED..... ..S..... 0,32-120,110 #7f090201 app:id/ivTabItem}
                          android.widget.ImageView{3365626 G.ED..... ..S...I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0904da app:id/vCrumb}
                          android.widget.TextView{3c67267 V.ED..... ..S..... 24,116-96,165 #7f09042f app:id/tvName}
                      android.widget.ImageView{5044814 G.ED..... ..S...I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0901c4 app:id/imvVip}
                    android.widget.FrameLayout{440f8bd VFE...C.. ........ 640,0-960,192}
                      android.widget.RelativeLayout{aa1aeb2 V.E...... ........ 0,0-320,192 #7f09055a app:id/vgTab}
                        android.widget.RelativeLayout{9bdce03 V.E...... ........ 99,0-221,192 #7f090518 app:id/vgItem}
                          android.widget.ImageView{3e7d180 V.ED..... ........ 0,32-122,110 #7f090201 app:id/ivTabItem}
                          android.widget.ImageView{48963b9 G.ED..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0904da app:id/vCrumb}
                          android.widget.TextView{4f803fe V.ED..... ........ 33,116-89,165 #7f09042f app:id/tvName}
                      android.widget.ImageView{345475f G.ED..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0901c4 app:id/imvVip}
                    android.widget.FrameLayout{2b885ac VF....... ........ 960,0-1280,192}
                      android.widget.RelativeLayout{538275 V.E...C.. ........ 0,0-320,192 #7f09055a app:id/vgTab}
                        android.widget.RelativeLayout{cc620a V.E...... ........ 100,0-220,192 #7f090518 app:id/vgItem}
                          android.widget.ImageView{aa0fa7b V.ED..... ........ 0,32-120,110 #7f090201 app:id/ivTabItem}
                          android.widget.ImageView{8fe5098 G.ED..... ......ID 81,21-102,42 #7f0904da app:id/vCrumb}
                          android.widget.TextView{e66d0f1 V.ED..... ........ 24,116-96,165 #7f09042f app:id/tvName}
                      android.widget.ImageView{d694d6 G.ED..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0901c4 app:id/imvVip}
                    android.widget.FrameLayout{cd3de44 VF....... ........ 1280,0-1600,192}
                      android.widget.RelativeLayout{868b2d V.E...C.. ........ 0,0-320,192 #7f09055a app:id/vgTab}
                        android.widget.RelativeLayout{97f2862 V.E...... ........ 100,0-220,192 #7f090518 app:id/vgItem}
                          android.widget.ImageView{73e3df3 V.ED..... ........ 0,32-120,110 #7f090201 app:id/ivTabItem}
                          android.widget.ImageView{9529ab0 G.ED..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0904da app:id/vCrumb}
                          android.widget.TextView{76dad29 V.ED..... ........ 24,116-96,165 #7f09042f app:id/tvName}
                      android.widget.ImageView{b2b68ae G.ED..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0901c4 app:id/imvVip}
```

I have the idea that this contains tab views while it doesn't work in another app. It seems not every app has infos like this. So I want to know is there any way to identify tab views in an android app, no matter using adb or analyzing the behavior when clicking a tab differs from clicking a normal view(e.g. when using tab+fragment, we can identify a tab when we click a view and the current fragment changes), or something else. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to identify the tab view in this way? I'm asking you, because if we know why do you need this, we can offer you another and hopefully an easier approach.

Comment: @TodorKostov Now I have a script to automatically click a view and I want to classify the clicked view into a certain category. Here is the problem now I have to solve.